SimpleScalar Installation on Latest Ubuntus and WSL (Windows 10) Problems/Errors
I am having a problem with simplescalar installation on 64 bit PC, as shown in the code:
make CFLAGS=-O                                                                                                                                                                      make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rei/Laboratoret/binutils-2.5.2/libiberty'                                                                                                                                                          gcc -c -O -I. -I./../include  getruntime.c                                                                                                                                                                                            In file included from /usr/include/time.h:33,                                                                                                                                                                                                          from getruntime.c:27:                                                                                                                                                                                                getruntime.c: In function ‘get_run_time’:                                                                                                                                                                                             getruntime.c:73:5: error: missing binary operator before token "1000000"                                                                                                                                                                 73 | #if CLOCKS_PER_SEC <= 1000000                                                                                                                                                                                                       |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                            make[1]: *** [Makefile:129: getruntime.o] Error 1                                                                                                                                                                                     make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rei/Laboratoret/binutils-2.5.2/libiberty'                                                                                                                                                           make: *** [Makefile:689: all-libiberty] Error 2
So we got 2 errors.
Environmental Variables:
export HOST=i386-pc-linux
export TARGET=sslittle-na-sstrix
export IDIR=/home/rei/Laboratoret
I am guessing the HOST name should be different (actually is: x86_64 - found with command uname -i). But in this case how do I actually write the HOST variable name?

AFAIK binutils-2.5.2 is THIRTY YEARS OLD - what exactly are you trying to do here?
